# W3WP memory and threads utilization every day at midnight

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, memory, w3wp, utilization

i have ASP.NET application (Microsoft "Stock Trader 5.0") installed on IIS 7.5 (Win 2008 R2) and i'm using in load application to load stress on the ASP.NET application.
every morning when i check the "perfmon" counters i see that around midnight (12 AM) i got memory and threads utilization problem (thread count jump from 150 to 1400, private memory increased in 200 MB for a few minutes).
this issue happened every day only at midnight, i tried to disabled the IIS logging, stop any schedule task that running around midnight, but i still got this issue.

there is something else that i can try or check to solve this issue ?

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the access log files in: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles

They might show any spikes in the number of requests that would explain the increase in thread count and memory usage.

You could also use profiling tools like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring) that will give you a "CT scan" view of your application.

Comment: i don't think that the problem is in the application, because the same scenario (transaction) is running all the day (as 100 simulated users), and the problem is only at 12 AM (midnight).

Comment: Inspecting the access log files will show you if there is an abnormal increase in the number of requests, which are of course not a problem of the application. You might find that other processes are requesting pages in your app.

Comment: i checked the log, and the only thing that i can see is that from 00:00 there is no incoming requests (before 00:00 i got around 650 requests/sec) for a few min, and then only after 2-4 hours it is start to be normal again.